# Intuitive understanding of Maximin Principle

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

From the the [book](https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/partial-differential-equations.pdf) page $324$, does someone could explain to me the *Theorem $2$. Maximin principle*? I have a bit of difficulties to well understand how works this theorem. A simple example would be appreciate in the explication, if possible.

> **Theorem $2$**. Maximin principle : Fix a positive integer $n \geq 2$. Fix $n-1$ arbitrary trial functions $y_1(x), \dots, y_{n-1}(x)$.
>   Let $$\lambda_{n*}=\min \frac{\| \nabla w\|^2}{\|  w\|^2}$$ among all
>   trial functions $w$ that are orthogonal to $y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}.$ Then
>   $$\lambda_n= \max \lambda_n*$$ over all choices of the $n-1$ trial
>   functions $y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}.$

Comment: This question is missing many essential details: what is $\lambda$? What space do the functions $y$ come from? What is the metric by which $w$ is orthogonal to the $y$s? What is the norm in the objective function? I'm sure all of this is explained somewhere in the book, but by making the question self contained instead of requiring us to leaf through a 500 page book, you are much more likely to receive a good answer...

Comment: @user7530 These information are almost explicit in the proof of this theorem. I think it is not useful to them in the matter, since this would only burden the question.

Comment: Well, if the proof of the theorem is important to the question, I highly recommend you copy it into your question, and point out the parts that are confusing you.

Comment: @user7530 I would like only an intuitive explanation of this theorem... not an explanation of the proof of that one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we're on a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and we've fixed boundary conditions. Recall that the Laplacian $\Delta$ induces an orthogonal decomposition of $L^2(M)$ into eigenspaces $E_k$, where $E_k$ is associated to the $k^{th}$ eigenvalue $\lambda_k$, and $\Delta$ acts by scaling on $E_k$. Write $0\leq \lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\cdots$ where we do not account for multiplicity. (For example, the Neumann spectrum of the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ would be $0\leq\pi^2\leq\pi^2\leq 4\pi^2\leq\cdots$.) Further, let $u_i$ be an eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_i$, so that $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the $L^2$ inner product.

> Think of this statement in terms of $(n-1)$-dimensional linear subspaces of $L^2(\Omega)$. Let $V$ be such a subspace. The intuition is dimension counting: the perpendicular complement of $V$ must "bleed into" eigenspaces corresponding to low-frequency eigenvalues, and the best you can do is rule out the lowest $n-1$ frequencies.

Let's formalize it this way. First, call the ratio $\mathcal{R}(v) = \|\nabla v\|^2/\|v\|^2$ the *Rayleigh quotient* of $v$, if it exists, for $v\in L^2$. Let $V$ be the span of $y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1}$. We're going to search for functions $v\in V^\perp$ which are *also* elements of $\oplus_{k\leq n} E_k$. Such a function must satisfy
$$ v = \sum_{j=1}^n a_ju_j $$
and
$$ \langle v,y_i\rangle = 0 $$
for all $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. If let $C$ be the matrix with entries $c_{ij} = \langle y_i,u_j\rangle$, we are searching for a solution $A = (a_j)$ to the equation $CA = 0$. As this system has more unknowns than equations, by rank-nullity the matrix $C$ must have a nontrivial kernel.

Denote by $\mu$ the infimum of $\mathcal{R}$ on $V^\perp$. Then 
$$ \mu\|v\|^2 \leq \|\nabla v\|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_ja_j^2 \leq \lambda_n\|v\|^2 $$
(Verify this for yourself with an integration by parts.)

Therefore we have $\mu\leq\lambda_n$. The subspace $V$ spanning $\{u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}\}$ achieves equality. This establishes the desired result.