# Proof - If one domain $D$ is contained in another domain $D'$, then $\lambda_n \leq \lambda_n'$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, laplacian

I would like to understand the proof of the theorem $4$ of the [book](https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/partial-differential-equations.pdf) page $326$. In fact, after a good while of trying to understand that proof, I am not even sure how it works. In being clear, does someone could explain to me the intuitive idea of this proof?

> **Theorem $4$ :** If one domain $D$ is contained in another domain $D'$, then $\lambda_n \leq \lambda_n'$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the min-max principle, which is intimately related to the [question you asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806263/intuitive-understanding-of-maximin-principle). Let's fix self-adjoint boundary conditions for the Laplacian $\Delta = -\sum \partial_i^2$ on a precompact domain $\Omega$. Restrict to the subspace $D$ of smooth functions satisfying those boundary conditions. Denote by $n$ the $L^2$ inner product. Then the quadratic form $q$ on $D$ defined by $q(u,v) = \int \langle \nabla u,\nabla v\rangle\ dx$ is nonnegative and has $q(u,v) = n(\Delta u, v) = n(u,\Delta v)$. (Verify this with integration by parts.)

Denote by $H(\Omega)$ the completion of $D$ with respect to the inner product $n + q$. (Verify for yourself that if the boundary conditions are Dirichlet, $H = H_0^1(\Omega)$ and if the boundary conditions are Neumann, $H = H^1(\Omega)$.) Denote by $\mathcal{R}$ the Rayleigh quotient on $H$, $\mathcal{R}(v) = q(v,v)/n(v,v)$.

> Min-max principle: The $k^{th}$ eigenvalue of the Laplacian satisfies 
>   $$ \lambda_k = \min_V \max_{v\in H} \mathcal{R}(v)$$
>   where $V$ ranges over $k$-dimensional subspaces of $H$.

Suppose we have two domains, $\Omega'\subset\Omega$. Let us fix boundary conditions. The intuition behind the proof is this: **Every subspace of $H(\Omega')$ is *also* a subspace of $H(\Omega)$.** Therefore the minimum in the minimax characterization of $\lambda_k(\Omega)$ is taken over a "strictly larger" set of subspaces than that of $\lambda_k(\Omega')$, and so we must have $\lambda_k(\Omega)\leq\lambda_k(\Omega')$.

Of course we cannot appeal to cardinality here. To formalize this intuition, instead use the fact that $H(\Omega)$ and $H(\Omega')$ are Hilbert spaces. Show that the embedding $\Omega'\hookrightarrow\Omega$ induces an isometric embedding. Use this to finish the argument.

---

This *does not hold true* for Neumann eigenvalues. Consider the Neumann Laplace spectra of rectangles. Can you find a counterexample to Neumann domain monotonicity? Do you see why Dirichlet monotonicity holds for rectangles, but Neumann monotonicity does not?

Comment: I think it is a bit silly, but the main thing I have difficulty to understand is $\lambda_k = \min_V \max_{v\in H} \mathcal{R}(v)$. Are you able to explain that we a simple example? Maybe for the eigenfunctions $X_n(x)=\sin (\frac{n \pi }{l}x)$ related to the eigenvalues $\lambda_n=\frac{n^2 \pi^2}{l^2}$ for the interval $[0,l]$.

Comment: **Another question :** Why do we define $\lambda_{n*}=\min \frac{\| \nabla w\|^2}{\|  w\|^2}$ like this?... for me, if $w$ is an eigenfunction (e.g., with Dirichlet boundary conditions), then $\frac{\| \nabla w\|^2}{\|  w\|^2}$ is only one eigenvalue, not a set of eigenvalues. Am I right?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity See the question I linked -- the proof for the minimax characterization is almost the same. (Find an intersection between $V$ and $E_{k-1}^\perp$, then show that a system of equations has a solution. Conclude that the inequality holds, and show that the inequality is attained for $V = E_k$.)

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity To your another question, I am in the process of writing an answer to a question you asked yesterday regarding intuition for the Rayleigh quotient $\|\nabla w\|^2/\|w\|^2$. Notice that $\lambda_n$ is the minimum over *all* $n$-dimensional subspaces of the maximum of the Rayleigh quotient on that space.

Comment: When do you put this answer?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity Apologies, it's half done. Am planning to finish after work today.

Comment: I have I last question about that proof. Why at the end of the proof, it is indicated that "in any case there are again more trial functions for $D'$ than $D$"? And in what the maximin for $D$ has more constraints?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity Note that every trial function of $D$ is *also* a trial function of $D'$, by extending it to be zero on $D'-D$. So there are "more" trial functions on $D'$, hence the infimum will be lower. (Again, you have to make this precise with Hilbert spaces.)