# Dirichlet conditions - Explanation of the proof of theorem $4$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition, spectral-theory, proof-explanation, eigenfunctions

I have a few difficulties understanding the first part (Dirichlet conditions) of the proof of theorem $4$ in the [book](https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/partial-differential-equations.pdf) Strauss W.A. Partial differential equations - an introduction (Wiley, $2008$, $2$nd Ed.) page $326$ in using the Maximin Principle ([Intuitive understanding of Maximin Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806263/intuitive-understanding-of-maximin-principle)). Is there anyone could explain this part in using $[a,b] \subset [a',b']$? I know that the eigenvalues related to these interval is one the form $\lambda_n = \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{l^2}$ ($l$ is the lenght of an interval) with the eigenfunction $u_n= \sin (\frac{n \pi}{l} x)$.

The maximin is just defined in the theorem $2$ page $324$.

> **Part of the proof :** In the Dirichlet case, consider the maximin expression ($13$) for $D$. If $w(x)$ is any trial function in $D$, we
>   define in all of $D'$ by setting it equal to zero outside $D$; that
>   is,
>
> $w'(x) =   \begin{cases}
>      w(x)       & \quad \text{if } x \in D\\
>      0  & \quad \text{if } x \in D' - D\\   \end{cases}. $
>
> Thus every trial function in $D$ corresponds to a trial function in
>   $D$ (but not conversely). So, compared to the trial functions for
>   $D'$, the trial functions for $D$ have the extra constraint of
>   vanishing in the rest of $D'$. By the principal ($17$), the maximin
>   for $D$ is larger than the maximin for $D'$. It follows that
>   $\lambda_n \geq \lambda_n'$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: you might want to write out the specific part of the proof you are referencing to make it easier for others to help you

Comment: @William I've done what you proposed. I think my problem is probably using the Maximin Principle.