# Dirichlet conditions - Proof of theorem $4$ on an example

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a few difficulties understanding the first part (Dirichlet conditions) of the proof of theorem $4$ in the book Strauss W.A. Partial differential equations - an introduction (Wiley, $2008$, $2$nd Ed.) page $326$ in using the Maximin Principle (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806263/intuitive-understanding-of-maximin-principle). Is there anyone could explain this part in using $[a,b] \subset [a',b']$? I know that the eigenvalues related to these interval is one the form $\lambda_n = \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{l^2}$ ($l$ is the lenght of an interval) with the eigenfunction $u_n= \sin (\frac{n \pi}{l} x)$.

The maximin is just defined in the theorem $2$ page $324$.

> **Part of the proof :** In the Dirichlet case, consider the maximin expression ($13$) for $D$. If $w(x)$ is any trial function in $D$, we
>   define in all of $D'$ by setting it equal to zero outside $D$; that
>   is,
>
> $w'(x) =   \begin{cases}
>      w(x)       & \quad \text{if } x \in D\\
>      0  & \quad \text{if } x \in D' - D\\   \end{cases}. $
>
> Thus every trial function in $D$ corresponds to a trial function in
>   $D$ (but not conversely). So, compared to the trial functions for
>   $D'$, the trial functions for $D$ have the extra constraint of
>   vanishing in the rest of $D'$. By the principal ($17$), the maximin
>   for $D$ is larger than the maximin for $D'$. It follows that
>   $\lambda_n \geq \lambda_n'$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: It is considered bad practice, since it can lead to people on one site spending time writing answers unaware that the question is getting attention on the other site. Moreover, comments and dialogue in one place are not going to be seen at the other